# I AM INSTALLING WSO2 API MANAGER ON GOOGLE KUBERNETS VER 1.19 the helm chart on git hub works for kubernetes ver 1.12 how make it work1.19

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, wso2, kubernetes-helm

I folow wso2 API MANAGER ON LIN K  instruction https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/wso2/am-single-node

`git clone https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim.git`then  updating three files named  wso2am-gateway-ingress.yaml,  wso2am-ingress.yaml   and  wso2am-websub-ingress.yaml on installation directory `~/kubernetes-apim/simple/am-single/templates/am`  match nginx ingress controller   with link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress
then i installed WSO2 by run the code
`helm install <RELEASE_NAME> <HELM_HOME>/am-single --version 4.0.0-1 --namespace <NAMESPACE> --dependency-update --create-namespace`

the code run successfully on G8S Cluster ver1.19

but i cant access the service
See my link to access the services
API Manager Publisher: http://35.245.157.84/publisher
API Manager DevPortal: https://35.245.157.84/devportal

what i did

I cloned WSO2 with the three files as shown below located on ~/kubernetes-apim/simple/am

file 1) wso2am-gateway-ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-gateway-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.hostname }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.hostname }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-service
          servicePort: 8243
```

Editted to

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-gateway-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.hostname }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.hostname }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-service
            port:
              number: 8243
```

file 2) wso2am-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.hostname }}
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.hostname }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-service
              servicePort: 9443
```

Editted to

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.hostname }}
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.management.hostname }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-service
                port:
                  number: 9443
```

file 3) wso2am-websub-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-websub-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.hostname }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.hostname }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-service
          servicePort: 8021
```

editted to

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-websub-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.hostname }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.wso2.deployment.am.ingress.websub.hostname }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ template "am-single-node.resource.prefix" . }}-am-service
            port:
              number: 8021
```

please clone that wsos API MANAGER ON LIN K  instruction https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/wso2/am-single-node

i use the wso2 installation  on github by cloning the link

`git clone https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim.git`

## please advise to check my helm chart using helm ver3 to work on kubernetes version 1.19

See my link to access the services
API Manager Publisher: http://35.245.157.84/publisher
API Manager DevPortal: https://35.245.157.84/devportal

see the output of `curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k`

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to metal-contact-171112.
Use “gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]” to change to a different project.
dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-pc56l:~$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials beanworth-cluster-2 --zone us-east4-a --project metal-contact-171112
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for beanworth-cluster-2.
dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-pc56l:~$ curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: am.wso2.com
dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-pc56l:~$ pwd
/home/dmalamo42
dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-pc56l:~$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-pc56l:~$ curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2017, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
  ~ Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
  ~ in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  ~ software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  ~ "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  ~ KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  ~ specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~ under the License.
  -->

<html lang="en">


<head>
    <base href="/publisher/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>[Publisher Portal]WSO2 APIM</title>

    <link href="/publisher/site/public/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/publisher/site/public/css/draftjs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/publisher/site/public/images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="react-root">
        <div class="apim-dual-ring"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="/publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/MaterialIcons.js"></script>
    <script src="/publisher/site/public/conf/userThemes.js"></script>
    <script src="/publisher/site/public/conf/portalSettings.js"></script>
    <script src="/publisher/services/settings/settings.js"></script>
    <script src="/publisher/site/public/dist/index.7422e2feefc0de743eb6.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- Swagger worker has being removed until we resolve
     *              https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/10694 issue, need to change webpack config too -->
    <!--script src="/publisher/"></script-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/material-icons.css">
</body>

</html>dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-pc56l:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found in [kubernetes-apim docs](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/simple/am-single/README.md#3-add-a-dns-record-mapping-the-hostnames-and-the-external-ip):

> ##### 3. Add a DNS record mapping the hostnames and the external IP
>
> If the defined hostnames (in the previous step) are backed by a DNS
> service, add a DNS record mapping the hostnames and the external IP
> (`EXTERNAL-IP`) in the relevant DNS service.
>
> If the defined hostnames are not backed by a DNS service, for the
> purpose of evaluation you may add an entry mapping the hostnames and
> the external IP in the  `/etc/hosts`  file at the client-side.
>
> ```
> <wso2.deployment.am.ingress.gateway.hostname>
> ```

So it looks like you need to either use your own domain and set Ingress hostnames in [values.yaml file](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/simple/am-single/values.yaml#L110), or add the already existing Ingress hostnames from values.yaml to `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: the ingress controller ip addresses

`dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-p76x8:~$ kubectl get ing -n beanworth2
NAME                                    CLASS    HOSTS                 ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
wso2am-single-node-am-gateway-ingress   <none>   gateway.am.wso2.com   35.245.157.84   80, 443   4d20h
wso2am-single-node-am-ingress           <none>   am.wso2.com           35.245.157.84   80, 443   4d20h
wso2am-single-node-am-websub-ingress    <none>   websub.am.wso2.com    35.245.157.84   80, 443   4d20h
dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-p76x8:~$`

Comment: eddited /etc/hosts file as shown below

`dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-p76x8:~$ sudo nano /etc/hosts 
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.4      cs-881542484316-default-default-p76x8
35.245.157.84 gateway.am.wso2.com
35.245.157.84 am.wso2.com
35.245.157.84 websub.am.wso2.com`

Comment: but still I cant access the pages below as per requirements
   API Manager Publisher: https://am.wso2.com/publisher
   API Manager DevPortal: https://am.wso2.com/devportal

by using IP address to by pass global DNS https://35.245.157.84/publisher and https://35.245.157.84/devportal  it returns 404 Not Found nginx  please advise what is wrong in my codes may be I eddited wrongly those files in my questions

Comment: Is your host (dmalamo42@cs-881542484316-default-default-p76x8) located on the same machine as the web browser? Also, please try to execute `curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k` from your host.

Comment: see the original thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720806/wso2-api-manager-version-4-0-0-1-helm-installation-issue-on-kubernetes-ver-1-19?noredirect=1&lq=1 and advise

Comment: see the out put

Comment: see the output of `curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k` on below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720806/wso2-api-manager-version-4-0-0-1-helm-installation-issue-on-kubernetes-ver-1-19

Comment: I have edited the question and add the output of `curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k`

Comment: Looks like curl https://am.wso2.com/publisher/ -k works for you in GCP, but in order to be able to reach desired destinations using your web browser you need to modify /etc/hosts on your LOCAL machine, not in the GCP.

Comment: THANKS IT works now..My code were ok but i needed to change values.yaml from am.wso2.com  to am.xxxx.co.tz  domain then   i follow your instruction to reconfigure newtwork services by adding  DNS ZONE records on GCP and also on /etc /hosts by adding  the domains name to my registered dns name am.xxx.co.tz  it is working  now and tested ok.. Thanks Team

Comment: Glad I could help, please accept and upvote my answer, thank you!